# How to join two dataframes for a particular condition for the joining keys

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have two datframes `df1` and `df2` and I want to join them and create new dataframe df3 .

I want join work even if `dest` column of `df1` has one match in `dest` in column of `df2`.

Join key is pair `org,dest`

**df1**

```
Name    org   dest  
Ashok   A      B
Rahul   A      C
Anupa   B      A
Sam     A      B
```

**df2**

```
org  dest   Amount
A       A/B/C   10
B       C       20
A       W       30
```

**Expected Output**

```
Name    org   dest  Amount
Ashok   A      B    10
Rahul   A      C    
Anupa   B      A
Sam     A      B    10
```

How can this be done in python

Comment: Shouldn't the second row have a `10` since A/C is found in both?

Comment: @mozway, you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the ids in "dest", then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = df1.merge(df2.assign(dest=df2['dest'].str.split('/'))
                   .explode('dest'),
                on=['org', 'dest'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
    Name org dest  Amount
0  Ashok   A    B    10.0
1  Rahul   A    C    10.0
2  Anupa   B    A     NaN
3    Sam   A    B    10.0
```

Reproducible input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [5, 6, 7, 8]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
                    'D': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]})
```

Comment: getting an error 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'assign'

Comment: @aeapen well, according to your question `df1` and `df2` are two dataframes, check your variables ;)